# Call a method in MVC .Net Command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, command

I'm new to MVC.
I have a button to do an export to excel.
On the Command class I have FilterData() and ExportData() method.
This data have been filtered from a FilterData() method with a select.

```
public DataTable FilterData()
{
   //My code to filter data
   sql= "select * from table where date = today()"
}

public IEnumerable<DB_Data> ExportData() //this is for the export button
{
   //My code to export data
}
```

My question is, in my Command class and as the result of the two methods is the same, how can I call the FilterData() method on the ExportData() method so I can export only the rows I have filtered?

Comment: You are mixing concepts, command is not the same as controller as in MVC.

Comment: Oh ok, so where can I use the FilterData() method? @AnandSowmithiran

Answer (score 0):

As `@Anand Sowmithiran` said those are two different concepts.

For your requirement you can do like below:

- In controller, get the data from database with `DbContext`.
- Then export data to excel from the above filtered data list.
- You can achieve this in `Code First approach`.

Thanks  `@Mukesh Kumar` for this nice article, [Export Data In Excel File With ASP.NET MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-data-in-excel-file-with-asp-net-mvc/).